# ExactTarget - Invite emails to non-subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like subscribers to be able to send an invitation email to non-subscribers to join our website. When creating an email in ExactTarget I am required to add the Profile Center, which does not exist for non-members.

Is this possible in ExactTarget? If so, what is the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

We actually have that functionality built in called "forward to a friend."  Have a look at at [this link.](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/forward_to_a_friend/)

Comment: We're making more of a "Invite to join the beta" system in which the user can send/cancel invitations. The "Forward to a Friend" functionality doesn't seem to handle everything we need. For instance, if an invitation is cancelled, would we be able to send an email that informs the invited user?

Comment: Who would do the canceling?  The subscriber who did the initial forward to a friend?  Or the website?

Comment: The subscriber who sent the initial invite.

Comment: I do not believe what you're trying to do is possible then.  Because of the CAN SPAM regulations, almost all sending requires the recipient to be a subscriber.  The two exceptions are:

1.  Forward to a Friend
2.  Transactional Send (like a receipt)

Sorry I don't have better news.